# If two one sided limits exist, and are equal, the two sided limit exists( Proof)

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification

I proved this statement, and It would be super if somebody check my proof. I hope it's precise and correct. Some definitions for the proof.

1)$\lim_{x\to c+}f=L$, we write for any $\epsilon>0 \ \exists \ \delta>0$ such that if $\lvert x-c \rvert < \delta$ then $\lvert f-L \rvert <\epsilon$

2$\lim_{x\to c-}f=L$, we write for any $\epsilon>0 \ \exists \ \delta>0$ such that if $c-x< \delta$ then $\lvert f-L \rvert <\epsilon$

$\textbf{Theorem}$:

$\lim_{x\to c}\ f=L$ $\iff$ $\lim_{x \to a+} f=L=\lim_{x \to a-} f$.

$\textbf{Proof}$: "$\Rightarrow$"

If $\lim_{x\to c}f=L$, then $\forall \ \epsilon>0, \exists \ \delta>0$ such that if $\lvert x-c \rvert <\delta$ then $\lvert f-L \rvert<\epsilon$. Since for any $\epsilon>0 \ \exists \ \delta>0$ such that if $\lvert x-c \rvert<\delta$ we have $\lvert f-L \rvert<\epsilon$ it follows that $\lim_{x\to c+}f=L$. Since $\lvert x-c \rvert=\lvert c-x \rvert<\delta$ we have $\lvert f-L \rvert<\epsilon$ and hence $\lim_{x\to c-}f=L$.

$"\Leftarrow"$ Now suppose that $\lim_{x \to a+} f=L=\lim_{x \to a-} f$,

then $\forall \ \epsilon>0 \ \exists \ \delta_1>0$ such that if $ x-c<\delta_1$ then $\lvert f-L \rvert<\epsilon$ and $\forall \ \epsilon>0 \ \exists \ \delta_2>0$ such that if $ c-x<\delta_2$ then $\lvert f-L \rvert<\epsilon$. Then we define $\delta:=min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$ and then if $\lvert x-c \rvert<\delta$ then $\lvert f-L \rvert <\epsilon$ and this means that $\lim_{x\to c}\ f=L$ $\blacksquare$

Is it correct proof? Thank you for help!

Comment: The big idea is correct, however you have absolute values when doing one sided limits. Just delete those and it should be fine.

Comment: @User203940 thank you! I improved it.